# Variables with docker

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to do a script which copies a file into a docker, and I wanted to use a variable for the command "docker exec -i [name_docker]" (Well, my boss want like it).
The problem comes when the variable isn't making it's job.

It keeps saying that there's no variable

```
root@user:/home/user# bash -x test
+ set -e
++ docker exec -i dockerName
"docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments.
See 'docker exec --help'.

Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Run a command in a running container
+ cmd=
+ mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/testie
++ docker exec -i dockerName stat -c %a /home/ubuntu/testie/test
stat: cannot stat '/home/ubuntu/testie/test': No such file or directory
+ filepermissions=
```

That's the error it gives me

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cmd=$(docker exec -i dockerName) mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/testie
filepermissions=$(docker exec -i dockerName -c '%a' /home/ubuntu/testie/test)
sudo docker cp /home/user/test dockerName:/home/ubuntu/testie
if [ $filepermissions == 777 ]; then
   echo "Free"
else
   echo "Restrictive. Gonna give it freedom"
   $commandDocker chmod 777 /home/ubuntu/testie/test
fi
```

I was expecting to get rid of that script easily, but it seems like I'll carry it forever.

Comment: why dont you use environment variable

Comment: What you mean with environment variable?

Comment: you can set system variables using docker compose file and .env

Comment: My boss will hate it, gotta find another way to do it :/. Eitherway, I'm just a student doing his own practices, so, he's not very confident on me

Comment: Environmental or setting a key / value pair in an .env file are the two accepted ways of passing data from a (physical) host machine to a container. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) has a great article concerning environmental variables and the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) explain .env variables.

Comment: The `(...)` syntax is executing the command inside the `()`. I think (not tested) that the command should be: `cmd=$(docker exec -i dockerName mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/testie)`

Comment: @Mathieu But if I do that, I won't be able to use any other order with that variable. Being clear: I want to use my "cmd" variable to use: cmd mkdir, cmd vi. cm ls -lah...

Comment: Why do you/your boss want to copy a file inside the docker container? What's the goal of the task? I recommend either adding the file on build, or mounting a volume.,

Comment: It's something about certificates. I don't ask :_)

Comment: @Sayrer Maybe you could try: `DOCK="docker exec -i dockerName"` 
Then `($DOCK mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/testie)`

Comment: @Mathieu It's actually reading it like a text, so it ain't working